# Custom View Filtered by Taxonomy Term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I've been reading sites all day trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing, perhaps you can help me. I can't seem to find the right explanation or tutorial.

Situation:

I have a custom View (Content Pane) that generates a Grid of nodes from my Video content type (we'll call it Video Gallery). I created a Page at /videos which includes that Video Gallery content pane in one of the Panels. This is all working very nicely.

I want to be able to filter the results though based on the url, so if they browse to /videos/foo then I'd like to show only the Video nodes which are tagged with the term "foo". This seems to work just fine when I preview the results on the View screen. I've added a Relationship to the Term and added a Contextual Filter on the term id (converted from name). When I type "foo" in the Preview with Contextual Filters box and click Update, then the preview grid below shows exactly what I'd expect (only the Videos tagged with "foo").

My problem:

The view seems to work just fine, but I can't seem to get it to work when actually viewing the page. How do I get my Page configuration to pass along the term argument to the View so that the View can properly filter the results?

I set the path on my custom Page to be `/videos/!videotype`, I've set the %videotype argument so the Context is "Taxonomy term: ID" (with Argument Type = "Term name").. but I can't seem to figure out the rest of the settings.

In my view, I've named my contextual filter "Video Tag Filter" and in my Page configuration, when I edit the Settings on the above View Content Pane, it gives me a dropdown labeled "Video Term Filter" (which is different from Video Tag Filter, I'm not sure where the Video Term Filter name comes from, I've looked through all the menus I can).

It doesn't seem to work though. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it! In my Views configuration, under the Arguments configuration the incoming Argument was set to use the "Second" argument but the Term Id was the First argument.

I have a different problem now... but I'll post another question.